# How to use php curl to fetch address book of gmail

Tags: php, gmail

I am new to php curl concept. Is there any option to fetch all email addresses in address book of user (where email address and password be provided as input). How to do it using curl concept in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://github.com/greenba/Google-Contacts-Data-API-PHP

> This is a simple way to retrive
>   contacts from Gmail or a hosted
>   application from Google with PHP. This
>   script uses curl to make requests to
>   Google Contacts Data API.  More
>   information about Google Contacts Data
>   API can be found at:
>   http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

Answer (score 0):

HI,

Use [Open Inviter](http://openinviter.com/) to fetch address book from almost all email service providers